# hadoop-streaming How do I remove the trailing tab symbol

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How do I get rid of the tab symbol

```
 hadoop jar \
      /usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
      -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=1 \
      -Dmapred.job.queue.name=default \
      -input hdfs://yyclusterxx/hive_warehouse/xx.db/tab/dt=2023-01-03 \
      -output hdfs://yyclusterxx/hive_warehouse/xx.db/tab/dt=2023-01-03-test5 \
      -mapper cat \
      -reducer cat
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten the outtextformat to fix that
[image]